# php zend framework json Decoding failed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework

Im using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'testURL',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {userId: userIds, imageUrl: imageUrl, message: message },
        success: callBack
    });
```

and server side:

```
$data = $this->_request->getPost();
        $response = Zend_Json::decode($data, true);
```

But Im getting an error on server side:

```
Decoding failed
```

What am i doiung wrong ?

Thanks for any help

EDIT:

Ive tried that:

```
$.ajax({
url: STValentines.baseUrl+'/mensaje/sendmessage',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {userId: '111', imageUrl: 'imageurl', message: 'message' },
success: callBack
});
```

the same error

EDIT 2:

Here is once again js code php code and the result :(

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'testURL',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "{'userId': 'test1234', 'imageUrl': 'testimageUrl', 'message': 'testmessage' }",
        success: callBack
    });


 public function sendmessageAction() {
    $data = $this->_request->getPost();
    print_r($data);
    $response = $data;
$this->_helper->json($response);
```

RESULT:

```
    Array
(
)
```

Comment: is your JSON string in proper format?

Comment: Does `$data` actually contain a JSON string? Does PHP's native `json_decode()` work? Are there multibyte/non-ascii characters in the JSON string?

Comment: Your edits are incorrect.  Again, you're not quoting your object property names.  Also, strings need to use **quotes** not **apostrophes**.  PHP is VERY picky about its JSON syntax.  Your edited AJAX call's data should've been as follows `{"userId": "111", "imageUrl": "imageurl", "message": "message" }` to be a suitable test.

Comment: Still incorrect.  You're not looking at how my code is formatted.  Until you pay attention to the syntax of the JSON (no apostrophes, strings are quoted, object property names are quoted) it won't parse properly in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Crashspeeder should be correct at least in his data format.

> from the PHP manual -  **json_decode** — Decodes a JSON string

```
//correct json format
Example #1 json_decode() examples


<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

and

> Example #3 common mistakes using json_decode()

```
<?php

// the following strings are valid JavaScript but not valid JSON

// the name and value must be enclosed in double quotes
// single quotes are not valid 
$bad_json = "{ 'bar': 'baz' }";
json_decode($bad_json); // null

// the name must be enclosed in double quotes
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz" }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null

// trailing commas are not allowed
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz", }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null

?>
```

also you can use...

> json_last_error — Returns the last error occurred

to get error.

Comment: I think that the problem is that $data = $this->_request->getPost(); returns an array not string and thats why  Zend_Json::decode($data, true); throws an error :(

Comment: @gruber True, but $this_request->getPost('data') should have a json string. or you could try $this->_request->getRawBody(), which returns the raw post data.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it looks like the data you're sending might be incorrect.  If I remember correctly object properties need to be quoted.  Try this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'testURL',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"userId": userIds, "imageUrl": imageUrl, "message": message },
    success: callBack
});
```

Comment: What is PHP receiving? Can you post a `print_r($data);` and show us the results?

Comment: Your edit is, once again, wrong.  Your edited AJAX call does not look like mine above.  Notice I don't have quotes around the whole data section and that there isn't a single apostrophe in my data either.

Comment: would it be ok ?   $.ajax({
    url: 'testURL',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"userId": "test1", "imageUrl": "test2", "message": "test3" },
    success: callBack
});

Comment: Yes.  At this point, however, it's post data and does not to be `json_decode()`d.  You can just access it using `$data` as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1. Remove `dataType: 'json'` from the AJAX request.
2. In the action, use `return $this->_helper->json($responseArray);`. No need to change layout or anything.